# how to send data from javascript to server side in asp.net mvc 6?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I can't get data from ajax to server side. I don't know much about ajax. This is how I am using it. 'main' is the form tag

```
<script>
    $('#main').on('submit', function (e) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: "checkout",
            type: "POST", 
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(id),
            success: function (mydata) {
                //history.pushState('', 'checkout' + href, href); 
            }
        });
    );
</script>

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getData(string id){
    //string id will always be null
    return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: `ajax url` is `checkout` while `post actionresult` is `getData`..

Comment: `data: { id: 'someValue' }` and `url: "@Url.Action("getData")",` to generate you url correctly

Answer (score 1):

please modified function call on submit event..

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){  

        $.ajax({
        url: "controllername/getData",
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{id:value}",
        success: function (mydata) {
            //history.pushState('', 'checkout' + href, href); 
        }
    }); });
```

Give the Valid Url in ajax funation

Answer (score 0):

Sample Example to you....

**You should pass the data with parameters**

```
   var pData = {
            id:"34"
        };
```

**Jquery Code :**

```
  $('#main').on('submit', function (e) {
        var pData = {
            id:"34"
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/GetData")",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: pData,
            success: function (response) {
                var item=response;
              //success response
            }
        });
    });
```

**Server Side**

```
public JsonResult GetData(int id)
    {
        var item = new
        {
            elementid = id,
            currenttime = DateTime.Now.ToString()
        };
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = item,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

I hope this may helpful for you